# Joining a String using a delimiter only at certain points

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to join an array of Strings using the String.join() method. I need the first item of the array to be removed (or set to empty). If I have a string array such as {"a","b","c","d"}, I want to return only b.c.d.

If it can be done with a for loop, that is fine. I currently have:

```
for (int i=1; i<item.length; i++) {
        newString += item[i] + ".";
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `Arrays.copyOfRange` to skip the first element of the array:

```
String.join(".", Arrays.copyOfRange(item, 1, item.length));
```

### Demo

Comment: doctor livingstone I presume? A master come into view. +1

Comment: Tim that is perfect and exactlty what I was looking for. Bonus points for keeping it syntactically short also!

Answer (score 2):

You can do it as follows:

```
String.join(".", Arrays.stream(myArray, 1, myArray.length).collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

or if you want the `.` suffix in the result then use `joining` collector:

```
Arrays.stream(myArray, 1, myArray.length)
      .collect(Collectors.joining(".","","."));
```

Comment: I think that trailing dot is a period (punctuation) and not part of the desired output.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Right, Thanks. just wanted to make sure :)

Comment: IMHO, performance is more important. That's why I can't give +1. It seems to me not so competent.

Comment: @snr using the `String.join` Tims approach is definitely better. I always keep forgetting you can pass an array to the join method. nevertheless, I don't want to change it now as Tim answered it first. but if you're concerned about the list construction then one can do `Arrays.stream(myArray, 1, myArray.length)
      .collect(Collectors.joining("."));`

Answer (score 1):

An alternative with streams:

```
String result = Arrays.stream(item)
                      .skip(1)
                      .collect(joining("."));
```

Answer (score 0):

Or this can also be a possible answer

```
String.join(".",myarray).substring(myarray[0].length()+1);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
String[] a = new String[] {"a","b","c","d"};
    String newString = "";
    for (int i=1; i<a.length; i++) {
        if (i > 0) {
            newString += a[i] + ".";
        }
    }
    System.out.println(newString);
```

Answer (score 0):

try using following code

```
public static String getJoined(String []strings) {
        StringBuilder sbr = new StringBuilder(); // to store joined string
        // skip first string, iterate over rest of the strings.
        for(int i=1; i<strings.length; i++) {
            // append current string and '.' 
            sbr.append(strings[i]).append(".");
        }
        // remove last '.' , it will not be required.
        // if not deleted the result will be contain '.' at end.
        // e.g  for {"a","b","c"} the result will be "b.c." instead of "b.c"
        sbr.delete(sbr.length()-1, sbr.length());
        return sbr.toString();
}
```